# autoreleasepool and pool drain with ARC

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I would like migrate this code with ARC.

I know I have to use :

```
@autoreleasepool {}
```

But I have a problem with the two pool drain, I don't know how to do.

```
- (void)downloadImageToCache:(NSString*)_urlImage
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    if (!(_urlImage) || (_urlImage == nil)) 
    {
        [pool drain];
        return;
    }

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlImage];
    NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];

    if (data != nil) 
    {
        ...do something...
    }
    else
    {

        ...do something...
    }
    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the current approach?

Comment: @H2CO3: It is not allowed with ARC.

Comment: @MartinR I'm sure I've seen `@autoreleasepool {}` used with ARC. (But anyway, who cares about ARC? I don't, for one.)

Comment: @H2CO3: Either I misunderstood you or you misunderstood me :-) `NSAutoreleasePool` and `drain` is not allowed with ARC, you *have* to use `@autoreleasepool`.

Comment: @MartinR Ah OK. It turns out I misunderstood the whole thing. It seemed quite obvious for me, apparently not for OP. You're right.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the whole thing. Don't worry about the returns. It will figure it out.

I.e. the compiler will convert it to the logically equivalent:  (or you can explicitly clean up the logic)

```
- (void)downloadImageToCache:(NSString*)_urlImage
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  if (!(_urlImage) || (_urlImage == nil))
  {
    //[pool drain];
    //return;
  } else {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlImage];
    NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];

    if (data != nil)
    {
      ...do something...
    }
    else
    {  
      ...do something...
    }
  }
  [pool drain];
}
```

which reduces to:

```
- (void)downloadImageToCache:(NSString*)_urlImage {
  @autoreleasepool {
    if (_urlImage != nil) {

      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlImage];
      NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];

      if (data != nil) {
        // ...do something...
      } else {
        //...do something...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or perhaps (fewer nested indentions are always my preference):

```
- (void)downloadImageToCache:(NSString*)_urlImage {
  if (_urlImage == nil) {
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@] Error Message", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    return;
  }

  @autoreleasepool {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlImage];
    NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];

    if (data != nil) {
      // ...do something...
    } else {
      //...do something...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just noting that you can still use `@autoreleasepool` with ARC. I wasn't sure. But then my consumed memory dropped from 1.5 GB to 100 MB.

Answer (score 1):

You can just "early-return" from the autorelease pool, that will release
all objects from the pool:

```
- (void)downloadImageToCache:(NSString*)_urlImage
{
    @autoreleasepool {    
       if (!(_urlImage) || (_urlImage == nil)) 
       {
           // no need (not allowed) to call `drain`
           return;
       }

       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlImage];
       NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];

       if (data != nil) 
       {
           ...do something...
       }
       else
       {

           ...do something...
       }
       // no need (not allowed) to call `drain`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new @autorelease block syntax, the pool will be drained when execution exits the block. So you can just do this:

```
- (void)downloadImageToCache:(NSString*)_urlImage
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        if (!(_urlImage) || (_urlImage == nil)) 
        {
            return; //leaves @autoreleasepool block, automatically drains
        }

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlImage];
        NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];

        if (data != nil) 
        {
            ...do something...
        }
        else
        {

            ...do something...
        }
    } //leaves @autoreleasepool block, automatically drains
}
```

See [AutoreleasePools](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
- (void)downloadImageToCache:(NSString*)_urlImage
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        if (!(_urlImage) || (_urlImage == nil))
        {
            return;
        }

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlImage];
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

        if (data != nil)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

From: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason there are two drains in this code is because it is returning early right after the first drain. Just wrap the code in `@autoreleasepool`, it will drain when it exits regardless of which return path is followed.